# extract images from pdf using pdfbox 1.83

Tags: java, pdfbox

In the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705163/extract-images-from-pdf-using-pdfbox) it is explained how to extract images from pdf using pdfbox.

This solution is not suitable by pdfbox 1.83 because the function org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getImages is deprecated.

The function which should replace the getImages function is getXObjects.

The problem is that this function returns a  `Map<String, PDXObject>` and not `Map<String, PDXObjectImage>`.

How do i know that a certain PDXObject represents a PDXObjectImage?

The only solution i found was

```
if(pdxObj.getClass().equals(PDXObjectImage.class) || PDXObjectImage.class.isAssignableFrom(pdxObj.getClass())) {
}
```

But i think that this solution is rather ugly.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: *Is there a better solution?* - Well, that is the solution also used in the (now deprecated) `getImages`, and it's a fairly fast check. You alternatively could check whether `pdxObj.getCOSStream().getItem("Subtype")` returns the name **/Image**. BTW, checking resources alone makes you miss inline images.

Comment: @mkl [ExtractImages](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/ExtractImages.html) is the class for the task, isnt it ?

Comment: @LittleChild That utility class extracts all XObject images located directly in the resource dictionary of a page or indirectly in the resources of a form XObject referenced from that page resource directory (even for forms inside forms...) (On the topic, BTW, it also uses the `instanceof` test). *But that utility does neither extract inline images nor images stored in patterns.*

Comment: @David BTW, instead of that `getClass().equals || class.isAssignableFrom` you can simply use an `pdxObj instanceof PDXObjectImage` test. Somehow in my former comments I thought you used that, just a moment ago  I realized you do that in a too complicated manner.

Comment: @mkl: You are right. How do i extract the inline images and images stored in patterns?

Comment: You can improve the `ExtractImages` class by making its `processResources` method also inspect the pattern resources, not only the XObject resources. For inline images I'm not aware of an explicit export method in PDFBox yet. You essentially need to parse content streams (of pages, form XObjects, and patterns) using e.g. a class derived from `PDFStreamEngine`  and process **BI** operands. The `PageDrawe  class (also derived from `PDFStreamEngine`) has a registered helper class `org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.pagedrawer.BeginInlineImage` to draw inline images. Look there for inspiration.