# Checking if a PDF is PDF/A 1-a format or not using PDFBOX in java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, pdfa

I have to check if a pdf file is in PDF/A 1-a format or not using pdfbox or any other free library in java . I have searched a lot on google in this regard but still i couldnt get any code or technique for doing this.

How can I check this in java .

Comment: What about [PDFBOX PDF/A validation](https://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/pdfavalidation.html))?

Comment: There they have only mentioned the validation for PDF/A-1b format . No proper documantation or explanation is given.

Comment: As far as I know, **itext** is the unbeatable champion (Lowagie thanks) - you could search there. For the rest PDFLib 7 is used for validation, but you probably know already.

Comment: @Sameer Do you really have to check whether it **is** PDF/A-1a or does it suffice to check whether it **claims to be** PDF/A-1a? The former one is not trivial.

Comment: @sameersingh What "documentation" do you need? PDFBox preflight tells you that it is PDF/A-1b, or why it is not. For further information, you will need to buy the PDF/A-1b specification.

Comment: @tilman I actually wanted to check if its PDF/A-1a or not ... so the below code is working fine I have checked it with few sample PDFs.

Comment: PDFBox preflight does not check for PDF/A-1a, only PDF/A-1b. The small "b" means "basic", the small "a" means "accessible", i.e. good for people with vision problems who need a screenreader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The document from pdfbox shows how to do PDF/A-1b validation:

https://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/pdfavalidation.html

to do pdf/a-1a validation, you simply change :

```
  parser.parse();
```

to:

```
 parser.parse(Format.PDF_A1A);
```

I was able to ascertain this from reading the parser source code located here:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pdfbox/preflight/1.8.2/org/apache/pdfbox/preflight/parser/PreflightParser.java

Comment: Source code is here: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/preflight/?sortby=date

Comment: can we check if the pdf or the images in the pdf are color or not and also find their pixel density.

Comment: that's another question altogether. but... you can extract the images and determine their pixel density (h x w): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705163/extract-images-from-pdf-using-pdfbox , but i don't know how to tell if an image is "color".

Comment: It seems that In 2.0.4 this has been removed, no documentation and no way out apparently. Any idea? I'll share my solution (if I found one)

Comment: update the link to https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/pdfavalidation.html