# Encounter images in between the text while parsing pdf using tika-server

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, pdfbox, apache-tika

I am able to fetch all the images and get the coordinates from the pdf using pdfbox. 
But when I parse the pdf using tika server, I get the text only. So how will I know when the image occures so that I can put the image exactly after that text.
I am using the code given in the following 1st answer:
[extract images from pdf using pdfbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705163/extract-images-from-pdf-using-pdfbox)

I am using tika server 1.7 I am talking the data of the pdf in the parser and using plain text version. I just want to know while parsing, how I will know that an image is encountered.

I got the HTML output using the praseToHTML() at this link https://tika.apache.org/1.10/examples.html 
But still this is not giving me the images present in the pdf. Nor it is giving any  tag.

Comment: Please mention what TIKA version you're using. See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1396

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika? Are you asking Tika for the HTML version, or the Plain Text version? If the latter, what happens when you switch to the former?

Comment: I am using tika server 1.7 I am talking the data of the pdf in the parser and using plain text version. I just want to know while parsing, how I will know that an image is encountered.

Comment: Try with Apache Tika 1.10, and fetching the HTML version. I think you should get an `<img>` tag in the place in the html where the image sits. Would that do you?

Comment: Can you please suggest me some method or code to extract the html from the pdf file. I googled it but no luck.

Comment: "code to extract the html from the pdf file" - ??? PDF doesn't contain HTML, except maybe if a HTML file is embedded in a PDF. Or do you mean parse the HTML that is produced by TIKA? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, I am asking for the code of HTML output produced by using TIKA.

Comment: I got the HTML output using the praseToHTML() at this link https://tika.apache.org/1.10/examples.html But still this is not giving me the images present in the pdf.

Comment: If it doesn't work with tika 1.10, and if you don't get an answer here, then try in the TIKA user mailing list. https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tika-user/ Include a link to your file.