# Extract Only Images from PDF File in java using Apache Tika or PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox, apache-tika

I am searching for a way to extract only images from pdf files using either apache tika or pdfbox but the image should not get blurred. Please help I am new to pdfbox and apache tika. But show me the latest method for pdfbox 2.0.7 API as many classes and methods have changed in newer API's as compared to older API's.

Comment: Possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705163/extract-images-from-pdf-using-pdfbox/21301313

Comment: Download the PDFBox source code and get the ExtractImages.java source code. That is all you need.

Comment: @Gagravarr you should not only have marked this question a duplicate but you should also have indicated which answer of that question to use. Because all of the answers of the "duplicate" are deficient, merely one is less deficient than the others.