# Jpg with black background when extracted via PDFBox from a PDF file for images with define colorspaces, works fine for other images

Tags: java, image, extract, pdfbox

Trying to get save embedded images in pdfs using Pdfbox 1.6.
Works fine for some images but doesn't work(creates full black image) for those that have defined colorspace.

Colorspace details : ICCBased , Number of Components : 3;

PDXObjectImage o = (PDXObjectImage)page.getResources().getImages().get("Im0");
Both
   ImageIO.write( o.getRGBImage(), "png", file);
and            o.write2file(file);
return in same result.

Please advise how to save these images correctly.

Comment: Please use the current version, which is 2.0.13, 1.6 is from 2011. Also share the PDF (upload to a sharehoster). It may also be needed to include the JPEG2000 and the JBIG2 decoder in the classpath, see dependencies https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html . For how to get images xobjects with 2.0.13, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37176699/535646